# How can I determine what stdout "points" to in C?

Tags: c, posix, stdout

I want to be able to tell when my program's stdout is redirected to a file/device, and when it is left to print normally on the screen. How can this be done in C?

**Update 1**: From the comments, it seems to be system dependent. If so, then how can this be done with posix-compliant systems?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't, it's handled by the kernel.

Comment: But please don't do any magic based on that condition, like `ls` did 40 years ago, if you write general tools. Read *Program Design in the Unix Environment* by Rob Pike for the details.

Comment: @Roland Illig: There is a useful usecase for this, IMHO: default to do colored output when connected to a TTY but don't output the escape sequences when connected to a file. Of course, command line switches should be provided to force turning the colors on and off as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps `isatty(stdout)`?

**Edit**: As Roland and tripleee suggest, a better answer would be `isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)`.

Comment: This method is limited to POSIX-like implementations.

Comment: `_isatty()`, with leading underscore, is ISO C.

Comment: @Joseph: Definitely not. ISO C has no notion of "tty", much less such a function. Also, `isatty(1)` would work just fine (`STDOUT_FILENO` is 1 by definition, as all shell programmers know very well).

Comment: @Steve, @R.: You are right; my comment was wrong. I was misled by the MSDN `isatty... This POSIX function is deprecated. Use the ISO C++ conformant _isatty instead.`

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that you can't, at least with standard C in a platform independent manner. The idea behind standard input/output is that C will do it's IO from a standard place. That standard place could be a terminal or a file or anything else, that is not the consideration of C. So you can't detect what is standard IO currently used.

EDIT: If a platform specific solution is okay for you then please refer to other answers (and also edit the question accordingly).

Comment: That is also platform specific and not part of C standard. Please make me correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, is there any difference in meaning? I am confused.

Comment: I am assuming "Please make me correct" is a translation of an expression in another language (On google it gets about 60K matches, so it must be reasonably common somewhere) "Please correct me" is the more widely used expression and gets about 13,700K matches on google.

Comment: @taskinoor, possibly not in a literal sense, but it's not an idiom seen in English AFAIK.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey and Amigable Clark Kant, thanks a lot. From now on I will use "please correct me" :-).

Comment: Its meaning is clear, and normally I wouldn't be pedantic about such things, however its meaning is about being the most "correct" and it could give the wrong impression about how important correctness is to you. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Look up `isatty` and more generally `fileno`.

Answer (score 2):

If a Linux-specific solution is OK, you can examine the symlinks under the `/proc` directory for your process. E.g.,

```
$ exec 3>/dev/null
$ ls -l /proc/$$/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 12 03:28 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 12 03:29 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 12 03:29 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 12 03:29 255 -> /dev/pts/1
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 12 03:29 3 -> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this out:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen/

I'm quoting from the link:

```
freopen

Reopen stream with different file or mode
freopen first tries to close any file already associated with the stream given as third parameter and disassociates it.
Then, whether that stream was successfuly closed or not, freopen opens the file whose name is passed in the first parameter, filename, and associates it with the specified stream just as fopen would do using the mode value specified as the second parameter.
This function is specially useful for redirecting predefined streams like stdin, stdout and stderr to specific files.
```

Though I'm not sure if this'll help you find out what it is pointing to in the first place.

Comment: How does that tell you whether you're connected to a TTY or not ?